# Mantener misma anchura en las columnas sin importar el contenido

Tags: html, css

Estoy trabajando con una tabla HTML y tengo el problema de que las columnas se redimensionan segun el contenido.

Si miras las imágenes de abajo la columna CAMPO3 cambia su anchura según su texto.

La idea es que las 2 primeras columnas ocupen 30px y 50px respectivamente y que el resto del espacio se reparta equitativamente entre las demas columnas, teniendo en cuenta que aunque actualmente haya 6 podría haber 8 o 10 y debe repartirse ese tamaño entre ellas correctamente.

Aqui teneis el ejemplo del problema:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, este es el sitio de Stackoverflow en Español. Por favor traduce tu pregunta o usa la versión inglesa de Stackoverflow

Comment: Gracias y disculpa, ya está corregido

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has probado a usar el selector `child` para las dos primeras columnas?

-----Edito para que las demas columnas se ajusten al ancho de la pagina que entendi mal la pregunta------ (mis dicuplas)

Primero hay que decirle a la tabla que su ancho es fijo con [`table-layout`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_tab_table-layout.asp)

```
 table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;  
 }
```

Luego cogemos los 2 primeros hijos `td` (columnas) de la tabla y les cambiamos su ancho

Ejemplo: (sin [`nth-child`](https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/sel_nth-child.asp) dado que en Internet explorer da problemas)

```
tr th:first-child {
  min-width: 30px;
} 

tr th:first-child + th {
  min-width: 50px;
}
```

Te adjunto el ejemplo anteriormente comentado.

```css
.tg {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;  
    word-wrap:break-word; 
    /*Esto lo añado extra para romper las frases y que nos e vea tan mal el titulo*/
 }
.tg td, .tg th {
     border: 1px solid black;
}

.tg tr th:first-child {
  table-layout: auto;
     width: 30px !important;
}
.tg tr th:first-child + th {
  table-layout: auto;
     width: 50px !important;
}
```

```html
<table class="tg">
      <tr>
        <th class="tg-0lax">Neque porro quisquam</th>
        <th class="tg-0lax">Neque</th>
        <th class="tg-0lax">porro</th>
        <th class="tg-0lax">quisquam</th>
        <th class="tg-0lax">est</th>
        <th class="tg-0lax">qui</th>
        <th class="tg-0lax">dolorem</th>
        <th class="tg-0lax">ipsum</th>
        <th class="tg-0lax">quia</th>
        <th class="tg-0lax">dolor</th>
        <th class="tg-0lax">sit</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="tg-0lax">Neque</td>
        <td class="tg-0lax">porro</td>
        <td class="tg-0lax">quisquam</td>
        <td class="tg-0lax">est</td>
        <td class="tg-0lax">qui</td>
        <td class="tg-0lax">dolorem</td>
        <td class="tg-0lax">ipsum</td>
        <td class="tg-0lax">quia</td>
        <td class="tg-0lax">dolor</td>
        <td class="tg-0lax">sit</td>
        <td class="tg-0lax">amet,</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="tg-0lax">Neque</td>
        <td class="tg-0lax">porro</td>
        <td class="tg-0lax">quisquam</td>
        <td class="tg-0lax">est</td>
        <td class="tg-0lax">qui</td>
        <td class="tg-0lax">dolorem</td>
        <td class="tg-0lax">ipsum</td>
        <td class="tg-0lax">quia</td>
        <td class="tg-0lax">dolor</td>
        <td class="tg-0lax">sit</td>
        <td class="tg-0lax">amet,</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="tg-0lax">Neque</td>
        <td class="tg-0lax">porro</td>
        <td class="tg-0lax">quisquam</td>
        <td class="tg-0lax">est</td>
        <td class="tg-0lax">qui</td>
        <td class="tg-0lax">dolorem</td>
        <td class="tg-0lax">ipsum</td>
        <td class="tg-0lax">quia</td>
        <td class="tg-0lax">dolor</td>
        <td class="tg-0lax">sit</td>
        <td class="tg-0lax">amet,</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: No es necesario darle un ancho a todos los `th` y `td` de cada columna, con dárselo al `th` es suficiente, el resto de la columna usará ese ancho. El OP pedía que el resto de columnas tuvieran el mismo ancho y en tu solución no lo tienen

Comment: Lo del th es correcto, no lo tenía entendido así yo, y yo no entiendi que el OP pida que las demás columnas mantengan un tamaño fijo sino que el tamaño restante se autoajuste.

Comment: Es lo que dice el título de la pregunta: Mantener misma anchura en las columnas sin importar el contenido

Comment: Ahora me di cuenta, ya edito